# Target closest class if string contains value

Tags: javascript

I have a localstorage item that gets stored in the page head, the const for this is also in the page head so that it gets loaded once, the below code duplicates for all product card items that load onto the category page, this code is added inline in script tags into the product card include, so that the metafield can collect each products unique metafield value, to make the example simpler I've just put "hello" where the metafield would be.

What I'm trying to do is check if "string" includes the value "hello", and if it does the script should find the closest class called "container" and add html on to the end of it.

In < head > tag:

```
const string = 'hello my name is';
```

In product card include:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    if (string.includes("hello")) {
        $(target).closest('.container').after('<div class="pass">some message</div>');
    }  
}
```

I haven't found any errors in the code but I'm sure there's something obvious to someone who has more experience, would be great if anyone can help out!

**Here is my latest attempt to fix the issue, still nothing is being added in html..**

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() { 

  const string = 'hello my name is';
  const div = document.getElementById('6204142256316');
  
  if (string.includes("hello")) {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="pass">some message</div>');  
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="6204142256316"></div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `target`?

Comment: to give some context .container sits just below the inline script in the html, both the inline script and .container are within the div referenced as target

Comment: Could you please provide example code of the product card? If you have control of the html and JavaScript, you could add an id to each product card and then add the id selector to the onload function.

Comment: Sure I'll add this to the question

Comment: Also, is each of the onload functions inside of the product card elements included on the initial page load or are these dynamically being added to the DOM using AJAX?

Comment: each are inside the product cards - i've added an excerpt to the question now also. appreciate the help

Comment: I've added an update @WebSpence the id="6204142256316" will always be unique for each script. is this closer to working do you think?

Comment: actually I checked on codepen and it works... but not on the live site, which is strange

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Managed to fix - turned out to be just an issue with me trying to put liquid within the script itself, as soon as I made "hello" const hello = '{{ product.metafield }}'; it worked. seems like I shot myself in the foot by trying to simplify the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227430/discussion-between-webspence-and-jtr).

Answer (score 0):

Have the `target` be some selector the uniquely identifies the script element that each “product card” contains. For example, each script element inside of the “product card” could have an id of `product-card-script-${PRODUCT_ID}`.

The function set to `window.onload` does not necessarily know that it is in the context of the product card when loaded.

This answer assumes that you have control of adding an id attribute to each script added to each product card.

Comment: I can completely remove target from the script and instead do this $('.{{ product.id }}').closest etc...then I can make the parent container have the class {{ product.id }}, apart from doing that do you recommend any other things or do you think this will then make this work? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make any liquid render outside the script - so this now works

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() { 

  const string = 'hello my name is';
  const div = document.getElementById('6204142256316');
  
  if (string.includes("hello")) {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="pass">some message</div>');  
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="6204142256316"></div>
```

To show what I was doing wrong:

```
{{ product.id }}.insertAdjacentHTML.......
```

Even though liquid is rendered prior to JS it seems this should always be like the below:

```
const div = document.getElementById('{{ product.id }}');
div.insertAdjacentHTML...........
```

Once I did that it worked perfectly.